# If-statement: Best way to handle layering with same condition

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm pretty new to programming, but I've been trying to make sure I learn good design practices. My question is related to how to handle this sort of `if-statement` situation, as it seems to violate `Don't Repeat Yourself`.

I have a class with a constructor that includes a method to connect to a database. The method will write to a `string` if there was an error in the connection code block. I then have a process method that analyzes metadata of the database, and will also write errors if any are found. I don't want the metadata analysis to run if there was already an error in the connection method, but is this the best way to do this?:

```
public bool Process()
{
    if (ErrorLog == null)
    {
        //Metadata analysis code that may write errors

        if (ErrorLog == null)
            return true;
        else
            PublishErrorLog();
        return false;
    } 
    else
        PublishErrorLog();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How about just catching exceptions (catch(MetadataException) {}) 'inside' and then other Exceptions 'outside'? And I would suggest you always use "{" and "}" in any if statement even if this is just a oneliner.

Comment: Note that the condition which you present is not exactly the same, since you mention that all the `//metadata analysis` process would change the `ErrorLog`. The point here to me is rather to make the error handling part isolated. See my answer. That way, you concentrate your error handling part pretty easily. You could also make further function for it if you wish

Comment: `ErrorLog` should not exist. You are talking about an object that holds errors and control flow that jumps out of the code when one of these errors are created. In C# we call those `Exception`s and they should not be stored in a field. They should just be caught.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this code clearly belongs on CodeReview as the code behaves as designed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You final function could look as simple as this:

```
public bool Process()
{
    if (hasError())
        return false;
    //Metadata analysis code that may write errors
    //Note that error log may change here
    return !hasError(); //updated by juharr
}
```

**Explanation:**

The code you present may not be exactly same condition if the line with `//metadata analysis` could actually change the state of `ErrorLog`.

**Simplification Step 1: Single If-Else Loop**

Seeing your nested loop however, I would rather make the codes become easier to handle and to read by doing something like this

```
public bool Process()
{
    if (ErrorLog != null){
        PublishErrorLog();
        return false;
    }
        //Metadata analysis code that may write errors
       //Note that error log may change here

    if (ErrorLog != null){
        PublishErrorLog();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Basically, rather than making nested if-else, you make simple statement which can be returned first. Then you return if it is satisfied, else you continue.

This way, your code become single conditional loop - no nested loop.

**Simplification Step 2: Error Log + Has Error Combined Function**

You could further improve the code above still, given that your error logging pattern is the same, you could create function like this

```
bool hasError(){
    if (ErrorLog != null){
        PublishErrorLog();
        return true;
    }
    return false; //no error, can continue
}
```

**Final Code**

Then the `Process` function would look like

```
public bool Process()
{
    if (hasError())
        return false;
    //Metadata analysis code that may write errors
    //Note that error log may change here
    return !hasError(); //updated by juharr
}
```

Very concise. And you can repeat the pattern elsewhere too.

Comment: And at the end you can replace the last 3 lines with `return !hasError();`

Comment: @juharr You are right! I updated the answer, referring it to you.

Comment: I think this answer solves the issue more in line with how my class is currently written. Looking into how to add custom exceptions will require some homework and a re-work of how everything is currently working, but something I'm going to try to get down.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are valid. But to me this looks like a perfect case for using `Exceptions`. Anytime you would write to `ErrorLog` also throw an exception. Then you can have exactly one block at the top that handles the error.

```
public bool Process()
{
    if (ErrorLog != null)
        //At this point, the PublishErrorLog should have already been called.
        return false;

    try
    {
        // Do Metadata analysis that may throw errors
    }
    catch (ErrorLogException e)
    {
        PublishErrorLog()
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This has the advantage that the metadata analysis can be as complicated and nested as you need. It just needs to throw the exception.

EDIT:

As pointed out by Aron, this can be done without having `ErrorLog` as a class member at all. The log information can be stored in the exception itself. The catch block could look like:

```
catch (ErrorLogException e)
{
    var logMessage = e.logMessage;
    PublishErrorLog(logMessage);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would go one further. `this.ErrorLog` shouldn't exist. The `Exception` should hold all the information for the Error, and the act of catching it should give you the exception. `this.ErrorLog` adds unnecessary complexity/state to the class. Also, return `bool` is Error is an anti pattern.

Comment: Still wrong. The correct way to signal an error in C# is to throw an exception as opposed to `return false`. But if you are going to catch JUST so you throw again...what exactly are you achieving? Exceptions are not like Pokemon. You don't need to catch'em all.

Comment: @Aron How do I communicate an error has been thrown to other methods? If the connection method errors, how do I let the Process method know, just let it error again when it tries to read a table? Also, in the metadata analysis, I want to know all the errors related to specific critera, like all the field and datatype errors, I don't want to stop it when the first one is found.

Comment: @Masasar You shouldn't communicate an error to another method. You should communicate an error to wherever the request for "work to be done" came from. Then if the caller receives an error it should decide what to do with that information (including calling in the cleaner [method]). That includes if the caller continues to plough on, and tidy up after.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using your `ErrorLog` property to signal the validity of your connection. If the `ErrorLog` is a string, as I understand from your question, I would have a specific way to tell if the connection is valid or not, and don't rely on the nullity of the log.

e.g.

```
public bool Process()
{
    if (HasValidConnection)
    {
        //Metadata analysis code that may write errors
    }

    if (ErrorLog == null)
    {
        // no errors establishing the connection neither processing metadata
        return true;
    }
    else
        PublishErrorLog();
    return false;
}
```